# Amplifier for modulated 2kHz rectangular signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, design, high-voltage, power-output-stage

I want to amplify a rectangular signal coming from a microcontroller.

It goes from -3.3V to 3.3V and has frequency of 2kHz. It is modulated with a trapezoid signal, which means the modulating signal rises up linearly to +/- 3.3V, stays at +/- 3.3V and then falls again to +/- 0V. The rectangular signal oscillates in between.

The maximum output should be as high as 40V and 150mA.
Is there an affordable "surface mount" solution?

I was thinking about an op-amp but there are none available which are capable of the power and just cost a few bucks each.

Here is a photo of the signal (the shape of the trapezoid signal is just drawn to make it more clear that the rectangular signal oscillates inside the shape):

[image]

Comment: Draw a picture of input and output waveforms and note that requests for product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Just how "rectangular" do you need the output to be (rise/fall times)?

Comment: It should stay below 20u for each rise and fall time and frequencies up to 100kHz should be amplified well. So pretty rectangular i guess (:

Comment: This would be easier: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJpDe.png ...... is the envelope signal phase-linked to the square carrier wave?

Comment: If it is feasible I will take it.
Yes they are phase-linked.

Comment: Could you not directly use the microcontroller to generate the desired waveform? Sounds like a PWM problem to me, assuming you have a sufficiently fast PWM unit (you probably do!). Or, you could directly control a cheap DAC (or the DAC of your microcontroller, if it has one), since 2 kHz is rather benign.

Comment: The signal is created by the microcontroller. It is just about amplyfing it to 40V and 150mA.
Does anybody have an idea how to make this in a smart way?